# What is the exact difference between samatha and passadha?

Tags: terminology, pali-language

What is the exact difference between *samatha* and *passadha*?

Comment: Do you happen to have a quote of passadha illustrating its usage in context?

Comment: Passadha is the 5th of the 7 factors of enlightenment (bojjhanga). Ledi Sayadaw 'The Requisites of Enlightenment' p. 86: 'The process of becoming calm and tranquil in both body and mind when the mental distractions, reflections and thoughts abate, is called "passadhi sambojjhanga", the enlightenment factor "tranquillity". It is the mental factor (cetasika) of tranquillity of body and of mind (kaya-passadhi, citta-passadhi).'

Comment: This article actually has some good information: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passaddhi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

samatha is a term frequently used. No problem defining that.

Passadha is not easily defined by web search. It appears and Portuguese and greek.

here is a link referring to passadha referring to the eye center.
http://www.dhammastudygroup.org/msg/125kd.txt

Perhaps there are other terms for passadha that are more widely used.